# Recursive iterating over structures

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following structure:

```
var struct = [{
    "name": "Name1",
    "type": "type1",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Name11",
        "type": "type1",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Name111",
            "type": "type1"
            },
            {
            "name": "Name112",
            "type": "type2"
            }
        }]
    }]
}];
```

I want to iterate over all name-type elements where type is equal to `type1` and create an `<option>` element for each one of them.

So it would be something like:

```
var iterate = function (data) {
   var elements = [];
   for (var i in data) {
      if (data[i].type == 'type1') {
         var option = document.createElement('option');
         option.innerHTML = data[i].name;
         elements.push(option);
         elements.push(iterate(data[i].children));
      }
   }
   return elements;
};
```

It however gives me wrong results. And probably is very inefficient. How should I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative recursive approach for getting the nested data.

```js
function getElements(data) {
    var elements = [];
    data.forEach(function iter(a) {
        var option;
        if (a.type === 'type1') {
            option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerHTML = a.name;
            elements.push(option);
            Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.forEach(iter); // assuming only 
        }                                                          // type1 branches
    });                                                            // to iterate
    return elements;
}

var struct = [{ "name": "Name1", "type": "type1", "children": [{ "name": "Name11", "type": "type1", "children": [{ "name": "Name111", "type": "type1" }, { "name": "Name112", "type": "type2" }] }] }];

console.log(getElements(struct));
```

Comment: Cool, it works. The question is would it be faster than the recursive approach.

Comment: it is recursive, in this line: `Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.forEach(iter);`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must not use any "element" var, just try this:

```
var iterate = function (data) {
   for (var i in data) {
      if (data[i].type == 'type1') {
         var option = document.createElement('option');
         option.innerHTML = data[i].name;
         data[i].push(option);
         iterate(data[i].children);
      }
   }
   return data;
};
```